# Crystal report document load hangs

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Whenever the program reaches the below code, the program hangs

```
protected void InitCrystalReport(String _reportUrl)
{
    myReportDocument.Load(_reportUrl);
}
```

This situation only happens when I put the web on IIS (another server), but it doesn't exist when I run the application on Visual studio (Debug mode). I've also used process monitor to monitor the process to see if the file is access denied.

I've tried below on Web Server but none of them works:

1. Changing application pool to .NET Classic
2. Restart the printer spooler

**Edit**
I restarted the server and everything's OK now

Comment: If you have found an answer for your own question, please answer the question by providing an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem when i moved a new report to the test server. My fix was to set a specific printer through File.. Print.. to one i knew was on the server (in this case MS XPS Document Writer). Ensure you've used .dispose etc on the object when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is old question already answered, I also encountered same problem and after wasting one whole day, I got suggestion from @PhilKemreen answer. Here is how I fixed it in my case:

1. Open report in Crystal Report Designer and Right Click
2. Select **Design** > **Page Setup...**, Page Setup Dialog box appears.
3. From the printer drop-down list, select **Microsoft XPS Document Writer**.
4. Click OK.

Then I deployed the new report file on server, it works.